# How to properly add an apache sites-enabled config

Tags: apache-http-server, ftp, shortcuts

I am currently modifying an apache2 server and all I basically have to do is to add a config file to the apache2/sites-enabled folder. But whenever I see an apache server all the config files in there aren't actually files but shortcuts and whenever you doubleclick them with an ftp software you just download a file. When I  look at the file information it links to a file which is actually in the exact same spot as the shortcut. So here my questions:

1. Why are the configs in apache2/sites-enabled all displayed as shortcuts?
2. How do I properly add a config while which is displayed and which behaves the same as the 000-default.conf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are the configs in `apache2/sites-enabled` all displayed as shortcuts?

They are symbolic links. Debian (and Debian-based distributions such as Ubuntu and Raspbian) use these links to manage which site configurations are active at any given time for Apache on those systems.

> How do I properly add a config which is displayed and which behaves the same as the 000-default.conf?

Typically `/etc/apache2/sites-available` is where the actual configuration files for Apache reside on Debian derived systems. `a2ensite` and 
`a2dissite` are used to control the creation/removal of these links.

If you wanted to create a new configuration file, you would normally:

1. Create a new `.conf` file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.
2. Run e.g. `sudo a2ensite example_site` from the command line (where `example_site` is the name of the configuration file located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` without the `.conf` extension.)

Regarding Step 2, you can also potentially create symbolic links manually with e.g. `sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/example_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.

Comment: And the opposite of `a2ensite` is `a2dissite`